# How to clear data from keyboard buffer after DOS int 16h / AH=1 detects a keypress?

Tags: assembly, keyboard, buffer, dos, x86-16

I'm writing a program in x86 assembler to run in 16-bit real mode under DOS.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.code

start: 
       mov dl, 4bh
loop1:
       mov ah, 2h
int 21h

mov ah, 1h
int 16h

cmp al, 6bh
jne loop1

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

end start
end
```

Program needs to write "K" all the time and when "k" is pressed on keyboard program should stop.

Everything is ok, Program writes "K" all the time and when I press "k" on keyboard my program stopped but, when I press another button on keyboard ( nothing should happen ) and when I press the "k" button later, the program doesn't stop but prints the "K" all the time.

I think this is because this other button has filled the buffer and I don't know how to reset it or take from the buffer only the last part of the buffer where there is the code of the last button pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, keyboard buffer is not empty and DOS function [Int 16/AH=01h KEYBOARD - CHECK FOR KEYSTROKE](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm) keeps returning the first (non-'k') key. If the check detects some keypress, you should swallow it with [Int 16/AH=00h KEYBOARD - GET KEYSTROKE](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm).
Instead of

```
mov ah, 1h
int 16h
cmp al, 6bh
jne loop1
```

try

```
mov ah, 1h   ; CHECK FOR KEYSTROKE
int 16h
jz loop1     ; Jump if none pressed.
mov ah, 0h   ; GET KEYSTROKE
int 16h
cmp al, 6bh  ; Check if it is 'k'.
jne loop1    ; If not, continue. Keybuffer is now empty.
```

When you post some source code here on SO, it should be accompanied with information how it is compiled and linked, also select appropriate [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags).

Comment: Hey man, thank you very much. This solution is the best because it works! :D